# TLS Authentication between Servers and their Keystores Trustores

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2, keytool

Before I go to the main question, I do want to state my understanding on Keystore and TrustStores:

1) Keystore - Details of key (private key) using which I would do my authentication as a server

2) Truststore - The list of root/interm CAs and other signed Certificates from different domains which I trust.

I am trying to establish an inter-server authentication and data exchange mechanism. All my servers has FQDN format as  `myserverX.mydomain.net` where X is the index e.g. `myserver1.mydomain.net`. If my understanding on keystore and truststore is correct, when `myserver1` is requesting data from `myserver2`, it's `myserver1` who is client and `myserver2` is server.

In this way:

1) `myserver1` needs to trust `myserver2` so `myserver2` public key certificate should be imported into the truststore in `myserver1'.

2) The above will also be true when 'myserver1' is server and `myserver2` is client - except now `myserver1` public key certificate should be imported into `myserver2` truststore.

Am I actually getting things right here? Or is there any fundamental mistake I am making? My intention was to try it out with self-signed certificate, and then, get a proper root CA signed certificate for my servers. But I would be grateful if someone can explain if I am making any wrong assumptions here.

Note - I am going to use Java keytool and JKS-type keystore (with default symmetric key algo and size) and I will use either `-certreq and -gencert` or `-selfcert` to generate a self signed certificate for my test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it right but if you use CA-signed certificates the import step is not needed. CAs are already trusted, by definition, and therefore so are the certificates they sign. So your test is pointless.

Comment: "Import step is not needed" - You mean to say "CA certficate" import is not needed, but I still need to import my self-signed certificates, correct?

Comment: I meant what I said. It seems perfectly clear. Your question doesn't make sense. If you are using CA-signed certificates you aren't using self-signed certificates.

Comment: I guess what I was struggling to understand is what certficate the server sends when the handshake happens for TLS - and this would be my keystore location. If this was signed by a trusted CA the browser will just continue normally, otherwise notify that the site isn't trusted.

Comment: It sends its self- or CA-signed certifies out of its *keystore*. Your questions were about the truststore, and that's what I answered. If you use a self-signed certificate, the client has to trust it, which is why an import step to the client truststore is needed. The client truststore already trusts CAs.